# How to get rid of synchronous XHTML request?

Tags: php, ajax, json

How to rewrite the code so I can use the JSON data retrieved from `test2.php`?

```
function drawChart4() {
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/master/test2.php?zoekopdracht=ceremonie",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
    }).responseText;

    var object = $.parseJSON(jsonData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/master/test2.php?zoekopdracht=ceremonie",
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(jsonData){
    // do something with the data
    console.log(jsonData);
}).fail(function(){
    // react on error
    console.log("Whoops, that failed!");
});
```

This assumes you are using the jQuery JS library on the client side, which your code implies.